# Generic mysql file loader script bash

Tags: mysql, sql, bash, shell

I have a few dozen csv files of differing lengths and columns that I need to create tables for and load in the data from the files.

I know the general syntax for creating simple one-off tables.

```
create table test.example
(Email varchar(256),
Date date default null,
etc etc);

load data local infile 'example_file.csv' into table test.example
fields terminated by ','
optionally enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\r\n'
ignore 1 lines;
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to speed this up and create a general MySQL shell script if possible so I can get these few dozen files uploaded quickly. I'm envisioning something where I can parameterize the file name and set fields to general varchar(256). Is this possible?

Comment: Yes.  Ex 1 table per file, table column per column in your CSV.  Then how do you link tables from one to the other?  That is case by case.  http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: I spent a considerable amount of time googling around before I posted here. Your response doesn't really make sense and is not helpful for people struggling to understand new concepts. I'm looking for one table per file and intend to link them together using sql. It looks like the person below was able to provide the answer, but if you have a better suggestion, that would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible :)

You can create a script `upload_csv_to_mysql_script.sh` something similar to this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Purpose: To insert data from a CSV file into the mysql table

db_name="testdb" 
input_file=$1 
table_name="test_table"

table_columns="$(head -n1 ${input_file} | sed s/,/' varchar(256), '/g | sed s/$/' varchar(256)'/g)"

echo "create table ${db_name}.${table_name} ( ${table_columns}) ;  
alter table ${db_name}.${table_name} change column state state char(2) ;                                                                                               
load data local infile '${input_file}' into table ${db_name}.${table_name}
fields terminated by ','                                                                                                                                            
optionally enclosed by '\"'                                                                                                                                       
lines terminated by '\n'                                                                                                                                        
ignore 1 lines ;" > /tmp/mysql_query.sql                                                                                                                          

mysql -u'username' -p'password' ${db_name} < /tmp/mysql_query.sql
```

Then you can run the script by passing the **the CSV file**  to it.

`$ ./upload_csv_to_mysql_script.sh test.csv`

I hope this is what you required.

Comment: This is great thanks! One question I have is that I need to set state to char(2), which I would normally do in my alter table after the table create since we generalized everything to varchar(256). However I've been looking through the files and some have different naming mechanisms for "state". Can you wildcard a field in the script to be like "alter table ${db_name}.${table_name} alter column '%state%' char(2)"?

Comment: I have updated the script to alter the 'state' column to char(2). You can add other fields also if required. If there are many such fields, the script can be modified more to create a complete table structure as per requirement as well. 

Please upvote and accept my answer if it works for you :)